# Have a transparent background?

Tags: java, debugging, graphics, paint

So, I'm trying to make this simple paint-like program, and it's been pretty successful until now, but I have this one problem. When I run the app, the background is transparent, and it renders the screen, except for that everything is working fine. Also, if I use super.paint(); , the screen starts blinking, flickering, and it ain't no good. I am currently using eclipse, following a tutorial, and the guy seems to be having everything work just fine. I am also an absolute beginner, so bear with me and explain everything please, as I have only been learning Java for 3 days by now.

```
package JavaMain;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class javamain extends JFrame {

  int x, y;

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private class AL extends KeyAdapter {

    private int keycode;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

      keycode = event.getKeyCode();

      if (keycode == event.VK_LEFT) {
        x--;
      }

      if (keycode == event.VK_RIGHT) {
        x++;
      }
      if (keycode == event.VK_UP) {
        y--;
      }
      if (keycode == event.VK_DOWN) {
        y++;
      }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
  }

  public javamain() {
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle("Statistic");
    setSize(600, 800);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    x = 200;
    y = 200;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);

    repaint();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new javamain();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First...**

You are breaking the paint chain...

```
public void paint (Graphics g)

{

// You MUST call super.paint here...

g.drawString("Hello World!", 250, 250);

}
```

**Second**

You should avoid, at all cost, overriding paint of a top level container like JFrame. Lots of reasons, one of which you just found, but also because top level containers are not double buffered, which will introduce flickering when the are painted and JFrame contains a bunch of other components, the JRootPane, the content pane, the glass pane...all of which could paint over what you are trying to paint.

Also, painting directly to the frame allows you to paint under the frame's decorations, which isn't really what you want to do...

For example (of why it's bad)...

How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized
How can I set in the midst?
Java AWT drawString() does not display on window
The solution...

Create a custom class extending from something like JPanel and override it's paintComponent method and perform your custom painting there. You gain double buffering support for free and no longer have to worry about the frame's borders, as the content pane will ensure that it's maintained with inside the frame decorations.

See Painting in AWT and Swing and Performing Custom Painting for more details

Also, call setResizable before setting the size of the frame, this changes the size of the frames decorations and can produce unexpected additional spacing within the frames content area...

**third....**

Then finally i will share a code that would really helps you to get some better ideas about what you are asking

```
    public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener 

    {

  private Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);

  private Point endPoint = new Point(0, 0);

  public Main() 

  {
    addKeyListener(this);

  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) 

  {

    int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    int d;

    if (evt.isShiftDown())
      d = 5;
    else
      d = 1;

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
      add(-d, 0);
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
      add(d, 0);
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      add(0, -d);
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      add(0, d);
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)
  {
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) 
  {

  }

  public boolean isFocusTraversable()

  {

    return true;

  }

  public void add(int dx, int dy) 

  {

    endPoint.x += dx;
    endPoint.y += dy;
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    g.dispose();
    startPoint.x = endPoint.x;
    startPoint.y = endPoint.y;

  }



public static void main(String[] args)

   {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Sketch");
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new Main());

    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```